# Conversão de char para inteiro no C#

Tags: c#, char

Lendo um artigo de blog, me deparei com a seguinte sintaxe para conversão de char para inteiro:

```
string value = "123";
foreach (var c in value)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(c))
    {
        int digito = c - '0';
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber por que essa conversão funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todo `char` é um inteiro correspondente da tabela `ASCII`, e o `'0'` é o valor base dessa tabela, ou seja, todos os caracteres tem um valor inteiro correspondente e em uma operação de subtração o resultado é o inteiro correspondente dessa tabela, por isso funciona.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [char (Referência de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char)
- [Método Convert.ToInt32 (Char)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ww9t2871(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [How to convert char to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665757/how-to-convert-char-to-int)
- [Char Struct](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [Char.GetNumericValue Method (Char)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

[Segundo a documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/x9h8tsay(v=vs.110)) do C#, [o `char` pode ser convertido implicitamente para `int`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/x9h8tsay(v=vs.110)#convers%C3%B5es)

> (... ) `char` pode ser convertida implicitamente para `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `float`, `double` ou  `decimal.

No entanto, cuidado com resultados inesperados. A [explicação do @VirgilioNovic](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/301567/78713) justifica porque operações como essa:

```
char op1 = '3';
char op2 = '1';

Console.WriteLine("Resultado: " + (op1 + op2).ToString());
```

Não resulta em 4:

```
`Resultado: 100`
```

Porque `(int)op1` é `51` e `(int)op2` é `49`.

[**Veja este exemplo no dotnetfiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UKeacS);

Answer (score 0):

você deve usar o ToString() para não usar o código ASC e depois o TryParse para verificar se é inteiro.

```
string value = "123";
foreach (var c in value)
        {
            short digito;
            if(Int16.TryParse(c.ToString(),out digito))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(digito);
            }                
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```